# Extract a global AWR report using SQL query

Tags: oracle

How do I generate a global AWR report in a RAC environment using a SQL query? I do not have Enterprise Manager access but only has execute privilege on DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following query, 1st arguent is the database id, the 2nd is a list of instances/nodes, 3rd & 4th are begin and end snap ids.

```
SELECT output FROM table(dbms_workload_repository.AWR_GLOBAL_REPORT_HTML(123456, '1,2,3', 38692, 38695))
```

Note: I specifically googled to find how I can pass the instance ids list as an argument and didn't find an example. So thought of sharing one.

Comment: Why use google? [this is all documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_workload_repos.htm#ARPLS093) "*The first overload accepts a comma-separated list of instance numbers*"

Comment: My oversight! Hope the example shows up in Google and helps others who doesn't read the documentation carefully like me :)